# DRb -- Marshal via JSON to accommodate a non-ruby remote object

Tags: ruby, json, drb

I need communication between a couple of process types, most of which will be ruby processes, but a very important process type I'll need to communicate with will be a python process.

I came across DRb and I think it might be suitable for that as an alternative to using my own communication protocol.

I wonder, is there a straightforward way to accommodate the python process type.

The python process type would only need to respond to messages of the type 
`message_id, *JSONifiable_params`.

In other words, I'd like to do something like (in ruby):

`python_server = DRbObject.new_with_uri(PYTHON_SERVER_URI, marshalling: :json)`

and then in python, handle whatever JSON gets sent for the method calls I want it to support.

Comment: I have not tested full integration with python before but [This Article](http://www.decalage.info/python/ruby_bridge) offers some ideas for running Ruby in Python so the reverse should be applicable as well. Also there are a few libraries such as `RubyPython` and `rupy` that might be of some interest to you since this is such a limited use case. Beyond that you could compile the python into a `dll` or com and then use `Win32Api` or `Win32Ole` to handle the calls to the `dll`.

Answer (score 0):

We implemented the Ruby side of a JSON Drb server for the [COSMOS](http://cosmosrb.com/) command and control system here: [json_drb.rb](https://github.com/BallAerospace/COSMOS/blob/master/lib/cosmos/io/json_drb.rb). We also have a Python interface which talks to that JSON Drb server at [python-ballcosmos](https://github.com/BallAerospace/python-ballcosmos).